# python MODBUS library allowing custom function codes

Tags: python, python-2.7, modbus

I am looking for a python (using version 2.7) MODBUS library (supports RTU) that would allow me to use custom function codes.

Looking at the following libraries's documentation I did not see where I could use custom function codes (may have missed it):

```
pymodbus
MinimalModbus
Modbus-tk
```

Do any of these libraries support custom function codes?

If not is there a library out there that does or do I need to create my own.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The MinimalModbus library allows you to do that. I have written about it in the documentation: https://minimalmodbus.readthedocs.org/en/master/develop.html#extending-minimalmodbus

Use this if you are to implement other Modbus function codes, as it takes care of CRC generation etc. Note that you need to build the payload yourself.